# usermanager updateasync return internal 500 error

Tags: asp.net-core, webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I am using asp.net core Identity for storing users. While I update a user Api returns a 500 internal error. I don't have an issue in user creation. Here's my code

**MvcController**

```
            var mem = new MembershipUser();
            HttpClient client2 = api.Initial();
            HttpResponseMessage responseTask2 = await client2.GetAsync("identity/GetUserById/" + user.IdentityKey);
            //("identity/GetUser/" + user.LoginName);
            if (responseTask2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTask2 = responseTask2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                mem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MembershipUser>(readTask2);
            }

            HttpClient client = api.Initial();
            var postTask = client.PutAsJsonAsync("identity/" + UserId, mem);
            postTask.Wait();
```

**ApiController**

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
    [Route("[action]/{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Put(int id, [FromBody] MembershipUser mem)
    {
        var resultCreate = await userManager.UpdateAsync(mem);
        if (resultCreate.Succeeded)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created, mem);
        }
        else
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound, mem);
        }
    }
```

The error is getting from api controlller updateasync section. What is the mistake I made ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Wrap your update async with try/catch then debug or log the inner exception, you will resolve your issue just with hard work

Comment: Hi @shine,please share the detailed error message to us.